# How can I call "Reset cold" and "Start" in the code?

Tags: plc, twincat

I want to make a "Reset cold" and right after that a "Start" in the plc code.

What are the variables for these symbols?

[image: Reset cold - Image] [image: Start - Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35043979.html?id=1868200634473488282

You should be able to use the FB PLC_Reset and FB PLC_Start in the TC2 utilities library.

You may however experience an issue restarting the code if the PLC is not running after the reset as it then can't run the PLC_Start command on itself. You may have to run the start command from another system and/or using Beckhoffs ADS interface.

Comment: He could just use the [NT_Reboot](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35043979.html&id=1868200634473488282) as long as the system is configured to start in RUN mode and PLC bootproject is loaded properly and set to auto start.

Comment: @ziga this is true but would also restart the PC, possibly this is unwanted, I also wonder what TC_Restart would do.

Comment: it is the better option than NT_Reboot, yes. That would be the closest to doing a reset cold imho, unless there is some function that is hidden withing the cluster of infosys :) . Just need the PLC runtime to have the [autostart bootproject](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_userinterface/7738257291.html&id=) checkbox marked

Comment: all reset cold does is reset the plc variables to init values and stop the PLC. Is this not what PLC_Reset or rebooting the plc does too?

Comment: @michaelp there does not seem to be a direct "reset cold" option. If you want to do it from PLC code it self, this seems to be it. You can just pick your best option. What is the functionality you want to achieve? Maybe there is another way you of doing what your end goal is.